# Should I delete MySQL entries using a PHP script which users can run?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, web

I'm currently working on a website which will have many users on it. These users are stored in a table with each having a unique id. The website will contain projects that the users can complete and these projects are stored in a separate table with unique id's as well.
  I need to make the users have a page they can view which will display a list of all the projects they are currently working on.
  To do this, I am going to set up another table in which each row will have the user's id as well as the project's id that they are working on. All of that will work alright but I would like to allow users to cancel their projects if they please. I am aware of how to do this, but I have read that deleting rows directly from a php script is insecure so the user used to access the database from PHP does not have 'DELETE' permissions.
  I am wondering if I should just delete rows at will when a user specifies which project to delete or if I should just have another field and simply mark each user-project row as being 'cancelled' in another field so I can work with them myself.

Comment: option 2, that way if a project is accidentally deleted you can recover it.

Comment: 1) DELETE permissions are NOT insecure... it is very common for an application to have delete permissions for this kind of thing. 2) If you want to counter for accidental deletions a `deleted` flag might be the better way to go.

Comment: As far as the security is concerned, you should follow the "least privilege" principle. Create different mysql usernames that have different levels of permission: read-only, insert/update, insert/update/delete. Scripts should connect to the database using the ID with the minimum required privileges. So the regular update script can't accidentally delete something, only the deletion script will be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks all of you! That's the idea I had but I needed some extra advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is, for maximum security is, have a parameter in the database table called "isActive", or something of that nature, that is a BIT data type to represent a boolean. If that boolean is false, then do not delete the project from the database, simply hide that tables data (do not display it on the site, but keep the data stored in the databse). That way, not only is your database secure from malicious users who would like to destroy data, but projects can also be "re-instated" if they wish to re-instate it. If the project sits around for a certain period of time, say, 14 days, just have the server delete it, not the user, if you wish. This worked for me in the past.

Hope This Helps!

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach to this problem is to have a field in the table that can be used to mark a record as deleted. This would be the only access the general user would have to the table as far as deletion goes. Some people also have a full delete, which states clearly that it will never be accessible again after the operation is completed.

Personally, I prefer to retain full delete permission to administrators allow the user to only mark records as deleted. If you're concerned about space, add a last accessed field as well, and schedule at set intervals a call to perform a full delete on any records that are marked as deleted and have not been active for a certain amount of time.